# Formally étale maps of animated $k$-algebras

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, simplicial-stuff, derived-algebraic-geometry, higher-algebra

In [Lurie's DAG](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Elurie/papers/DAG.pdf#page=42), he defines what it means for a natural transformation $T:\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{F}'$ of functors $\mathcal{F},\mathcal{F}':\mathcal{SCR}\to\mathcal{S}$ to be formally étale. Namely, it is formally smooth and the relative cotangent complex is $0$. He also gives an equivalent characterization that for any small extension $\tilde{B}\to B$, the map $\mathcal{F}(\tilde{B})\to\mathcal{F}(B)\times_{\mathcal{F}'(B)}\mathcal{F}'(\tilde{B})$ is an equivalence, which is in essence a derived notion of the infinitesimal lifting property of étale maps.

Let $f:S\to R$ be a formally étale map of animated $k$-algebras. (Recall that the category of animated $k$-algebras is the $\infty$-category obtained from simplicial $k$-algebras by inverting weak equivalences.)

Is the fact that $f$ is formally étale equivalent to the statement that $T:\mathrm{Maps}(R,-)\to\mathrm{Maps}(S,-)$ is a formally étale natural transformation between functors of points from animated $k$-algebras to spaces, in the sense of Lurie above?

Comment: That's how formally etale is usually defined for simplicial rings. There are several equivalent formulations - see for instance section 2.2.2 of HAG2.

Comment: Thanks @JonPridham. Which definition are you referring to when you say "that's"? 

I've seen Toën-Vezzosi's definition of strongly étale (I usually use it), and of course in animated rings, $f:S\to R$ formally étale must be formally smooth plus $L_{R/S}=0$. I think I'm okay on any formulation of étale maps of animated rings that deals only with animated rings. My gap is connecting the dots from a statement of animated rings to Lurie's statement of functors into spaces.

Are you saying that "$T$, defined above, is formally étale" is how "$f$ is formally étale" is usually defined?

Comment: Yes,  "T, defined above, is formally étale" is how "f is formally étale" is usually defined.

Comment: @JonPridham, thank you!